# Foursquare and ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foursquare

does anybody work with foursquare api and asp.net, do you know some basic tutorial, how to set the environment, do I need some api, how can I make my app to conect to 4sq and ask something. I work with asp.net mvc2, and any clue on this would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of C# libraries available for the foursquare API, you can see the complete list here:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/libraries.html

In terms of tutorials, you can use the interactive query viewer on the foursquare website to get a sense of the data:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues.html
(click 'try it now' and it will give you an interactive query console for the api!)

You can also get a walkthrough of how to do OAuth2 authentication on the website too:
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/oauth.html

For what it's worth, when I was first playing with the API I found it useful to test out all  of my queries using cURL, then once you use a library you're already a pro.

Hope that helps?